# Debug NestJS CQRS by calling query and command without controllers?

Tags: debugging, nestjs, cqrs

I currently have a NestJs project using CQRS. To develop the app, I usually create one controller for each command/query to debug the associated command/query.

Is there a better solution to test queries and commands without having to create a controller for each to test them with postman ? I was wondering if there is a tool that can write on a bus dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to use a debugger in combination with an API platform such as Postman, there is not much you can do here. Postman needs available controllers or web-sockets to reach your API. But to test your commands/queries you don't necessarily have to code any of them, though.

You could actually use e2e or integration tests within your project to make sure everything is well plugged and works just fine.